# Using "In" in a when condition

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

OK, So I want to identify a value in MSA 1 is in a list of Strings. I have

```
HL7.{MSA:1} In ("AE", "AR", "CE", "CR")
```

That doesn't work, so what should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. it's

```
HL7.{MSA:1} In ("AE,AR,CE,CR")
```